# Connect to mongo service via domain name

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, kube-dns

I create deployment and service from *.yaml. Into container I find ns record via `nslookup` or `dig`, but can't connect to db via service name or service IP.

Anybody can tell me, what I do wrong?

**Environment**:

**Minikube version**:

```
$minikube version 
v0.24.1
```

**OS** (e.g. from /etc/os-release):

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.2 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
VERSION_CODENAME=xenial
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial
```

**VM Driver** (e.g. `cat ~/.minikube/machines/minikube/config.json | grep DriverName`):

```
"DriverName": "kvm2",
and
"DriverName": "virtualbox",
```

**ISO version** (e.g. `cat ~/.minikube/machines/minikube/config.json | grep -i ISO` or `minikube ssh cat /etc/VERSION`):

```
v0.23.6
```

### DNS logs

#### sidecar

```
kubectl logs --namespace=kube-system $(kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system -l k8s-app=kube-dns -o name) -c sidecar
ERROR: logging before flag.Parse: I1221 13:49:25.085555       1 main.go:48] Version v1.14.4-2-g5584e04
ERROR: logging before flag.Parse: I1221 13:49:25.085647       1 server.go:45] Starting server (options {DnsMasqPort:53 DnsMasqAddr:127.0.0.1 DnsMasqPollIntervalMs:5000 Probes:[{Label:kubedns Server:127.0.0.1:10053 Name:kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local. Interval:5s Type:1} {Label:dnsmasq Server:127.0.0.1:53 Name:kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local. Interval:5s Type:1}] PrometheusAddr:0.0.0.0 PrometheusPort:10054 PrometheusPath:/metrics PrometheusNamespace:kubedns})
ERROR: logging before flag.Parse: I1221 13:49:25.085854       1 dnsprobe.go:75] Starting dnsProbe {Label:kubedns Server:127.0.0.1:10053 Name:kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local. Interval:5s Type:1}
ERROR: logging before flag.Parse: I1221 13:49:25.086013       1 dnsprobe.go:75] Starting dnsProbe {Label:dnsmasq Server:127.0.0.1:53 Name:kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local. Interval:5s Type:1}
```

### dnsmasq

```
kubectl logs --namespace=kube-system $(kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system -l k8s-app=kube-dns -o name) -c dnsmasq
I1221 13:49:24.134834       1 main.go:76] opts: {{/usr/sbin/dnsmasq [-k --cache-size=1000 --log-facility=- --server=/cluster.local/127.0.0.1#10053 --server=/in-addr.arpa/127.0.0.1#10053 --server=/ip6.arpa/127.0.0.1#10053] true} /etc/k8s/dns/dnsmasq-nanny 10000000000}
I1221 13:49:24.135086       1 nanny.go:86] Starting dnsmasq [-k --cache-size=1000 --log-facility=- --server=/cluster.local/127.0.0.1#10053 --server=/in-addr.arpa/127.0.0.1#10053 --server=/ip6.arpa/127.0.0.1#10053]
I1221 13:49:24.353157       1 nanny.go:111] 
W1221 13:49:24.353184       1 nanny.go:112] Got EOF from stdout
I1221 13:49:24.353308       1 nanny.go:108] dnsmasq[10]: started, version 2.78-security-prerelease cachesize 1000
I1221 13:49:24.353340       1 nanny.go:108] dnsmasq[10]: compile time options: IPv6 GNU-getopt no-DBus no-i18n no-IDN DHCP DHCPv6 no-Lua TFTP no-conntrack ipset auth no-DNSSEC loop-detect inotify
I1221 13:49:24.353364       1 nanny.go:108] dnsmasq[10]: using nameserver 127.0.0.1#10053 for domain ip6.arpa 
I1221 13:49:24.353385       1 nanny.go:108] dnsmasq[10]: using nameserver 127.0.0.1#10053 for domain in-addr.arpa 
I1221 13:49:24.353419       1 nanny.go:108] dnsmasq[10]: using nameserver 127.0.0.1#10053 for domain cluster.local 
I1221 13:49:24.353457       1 nanny.go:108] dnsmasq[10]: reading /etc/resolv.conf
I1221 13:49:24.353487       1 nanny.go:108] dnsmasq[10]: using nameserver 127.0.0.1#10053 for domain ip6.arpa 
I1221 13:49:24.353514       1 nanny.go:108] dnsmasq[10]: using nameserver 127.0.0.1#10053 for domain in-addr.arpa 
I1221 13:49:24.353534       1 nanny.go:108] dnsmasq[10]: using nameserver 127.0.0.1#10053 for domain cluster.local 
I1221 13:49:24.353554       1 nanny.go:108] dnsmasq[10]: using nameserver 10.110.7.1#53
I1221 13:49:24.353617       1 nanny.go:108] dnsmasq[10]: read /etc/hosts - 7 addresses
```

### kubedns

```
kubectl logs --namespace=kube-system $(kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system -l k8s-app=kube-dns -o name) -c kubedns
I1221 13:49:23.122626       1 dns.go:48] version: 1.14.4-2-g5584e04
I1221 13:49:23.202663       1 server.go:66] Using configuration read from ConfigMap: kube-system:kube-dns
I1221 13:49:23.202797       1 server.go:113] FLAG: --alsologtostderr="false"
I1221 13:49:23.202924       1 server.go:113] FLAG: --config-dir=""
I1221 13:49:23.202932       1 server.go:113] FLAG: --config-map="kube-dns"
I1221 13:49:23.202936       1 server.go:113] FLAG: --config-map-namespace="kube-system"
I1221 13:49:23.202959       1 server.go:113] FLAG: --config-period="10s"
I1221 13:49:23.203028       1 server.go:113] FLAG: --dns-bind-address="0.0.0.0"
I1221 13:49:23.203042       1 server.go:113] FLAG: --dns-port="10053"
I1221 13:49:23.203082       1 server.go:113] FLAG: --domain="cluster.local."
I1221 13:49:23.203101       1 server.go:113] FLAG: --federations=""
I1221 13:49:23.203107       1 server.go:113] FLAG: --healthz-port="8081"
I1221 13:49:23.203111       1 server.go:113] FLAG: --initial-sync-timeout="1m0s"
I1221 13:49:23.203115       1 server.go:113] FLAG: --kube-master-url=""
I1221 13:49:23.203194       1 server.go:113] FLAG: --kubecfg-file=""
I1221 13:49:23.203198       1 server.go:113] FLAG: --log-backtrace-at=":0"
I1221 13:49:23.203249       1 server.go:113] FLAG: --log-dir=""
I1221 13:49:23.203254       1 server.go:113] FLAG: --log-flush-frequency="5s"
I1221 13:49:23.203277       1 server.go:113] FLAG: --logtostderr="true"
I1221 13:49:23.203281       1 server.go:113] FLAG: --nameservers=""
I1221 13:49:23.203348       1 server.go:113] FLAG: --stderrthreshold="2"
I1221 13:49:23.203369       1 server.go:113] FLAG: --v="2"
I1221 13:49:23.203416       1 server.go:113] FLAG: --version="false"
I1221 13:49:23.203447       1 server.go:113] FLAG: --vmodule=""
I1221 13:49:23.203554       1 server.go:176] Starting SkyDNS server (0.0.0.0:10053)
I1221 13:49:23.203842       1 server.go:198] Skydns metrics enabled (/metrics:10055)
I1221 13:49:23.203858       1 dns.go:147] Starting endpointsController
I1221 13:49:23.203863       1 dns.go:150] Starting serviceController
I1221 13:49:23.204165       1 logs.go:41] skydns: ready for queries on cluster.local. for tcp://0.0.0.0:10053 [rcache 0]
I1221 13:49:23.204175       1 logs.go:41] skydns: ready for queries on cluster.local. for udp://0.0.0.0:10053 [rcache 0]
I1221 13:49:23.555942       1 sync_configmap.go:107] ConfigMap kube-system:kube-dns was created
I1221 13:49:24.054105       1 dns.go:171] Initialized services and endpoints from apiserver
I1221 13:49:24.054128       1 server.go:129] Setting up Healthz Handler (/readiness)
I1221 13:49:24.054206       1 server.go:134] Setting up cache handler (/cache)
I1221 13:49:24.054257       1 server.go:120] Status HTTP port 8081
```

**What happened**:
Can not `ping` or `traceroute` service via service name or IP.

**What you expected to happen**:

`ping` to the service via service name.

**How to reproduce it** (as minimally and precisely as possible):

#### Default namesapce

```
$ kc get all
NAME               DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deploy/memcached   1         1         1            1           1h
deploy/mongo       1         1         1            1           1h

NAME                      DESIRED   CURRENT   READY     AGE
rs/memcached-64dcdbc9f6   1         1         1         1h
rs/mongo-67d67fddf9       1         1         1         39m
rs/mongo-6fc9bd6d6c       0         0         0         1h

NAME               DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deploy/memcached   1         1         1            1           1h
deploy/mongo       1         1         1            1           1h

NAME                      DESIRED   CURRENT   READY     AGE
rs/memcached-64dcdbc9f6   1         1         1         1h
rs/mongo-67d67fddf9       1         1         1         39m
rs/mongo-6fc9bd6d6c       0         0         0         1h

NAME                            READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
po/busybox                      1/1       Running   0          29m
po/memcached-64dcdbc9f6-j2v97   1/1       Running   0          1h
po/mongo-67d67fddf9-55zgd       1/1       Running   0          39m

NAME             TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)     AGE
svc/kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1      <none>        443/TCP     1h
svc/memcached    ClusterIP   10.100.42.68   <none>        55555/TCP   1h
svc/mongo        ClusterIP   10.99.92.189   <none>        27017/TCP   1h
```

#### kube-system

```
$ kc get --namespace=kube-system all
NAME              DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deploy/kube-dns   1         1         1            1           1h

NAME                     DESIRED   CURRENT   READY     AGE
rs/kube-dns-86f6f55dd5   1         1         1         1h

NAME              DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deploy/kube-dns   1         1         1            1           1h

NAME                     DESIRED   CURRENT   READY     AGE
rs/kube-dns-86f6f55dd5   1         1         1         1h

NAME                             READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
po/kube-addon-manager-minikube   1/1       Running   1          1h
po/kube-dns-86f6f55dd5-mrtrm     3/3       Running   3          1h
po/kubernetes-dashboard-5sgcl    1/1       Running   1          1h
po/storage-provisioner           1/1       Running   1          1h

NAME                      DESIRED   CURRENT   READY     AGE
rc/kubernetes-dashboard   1         1         1         1h

NAME                       TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)         AGE
svc/kube-dns               ClusterIP   10.96.0.10     <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP   1h
svc/kubernetes-dashboard   NodePort    10.110.68.80   <none>        80:30000/TCP    1h
```

#### resolv.conf

```
$ kc exec -it mongo-67d67fddf9-55zgd -- cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 10.96.0.10
search default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local
options ndots:5
```

#### nslookup test

```
$ kc exec -it mongo-67d67fddf9-55zgd nslookup kubernetes
Server:     10.96.0.10
Address:    10.96.0.10#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.96.0.1
```

#### ping test

```
$ kc exec -it mongo-67d67fddf9-55zgd -- ping kubernetes
PING kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local (10.96.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.96.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=250 time=2.873 ms
64 bytes from 10.96.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=250 time=1.845 ms
64 bytes from 10.96.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=250 time=1.809 ms
64 bytes from 10.96.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=250 time=2.035 ms
64 bytes from 10.96.0.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=250 time=1.805 ms
--- kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 1.805/2.073/2.873/0.409 ms
```

#### traceroute test (ok)

```
$ kc exec -it mongo-67d67fddf9-55zgd -- traceroute -n kubernetes
traceroute to kubernetes (10.96.0.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.110.7.1  0.207 ms  0.195 ms  0.186 ms
 2  192.168.1.1  0.317 ms  0.392 ms  0.456 ms
 3  10.77.0.1  2.261 ms  2.977 ms  3.755 ms
 4  10.128.132.1  1.568 ms  1.721 ms  1.934 ms
 5  192.168.39.136  2.055 ms  2.329 ms  2.456 ms
 6  10.128.145.2  8.603 ms  8.971 ms  9.391 ms
```

#### test nslookup

```
$ kc exec -it mongo-67d67fddf9-55zgd -- nslookup mongo
Server:     10.96.0.10
Address:    10.96.0.10#53

Name:   mongo.default.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.99.92.189
```

#### test ping

```
$ kc exec -it mongo-67d67fddf9-55zgd -- ping mongo
PING mongo.default.svc.cluster.local (10.99.92.189): 56 data bytes
--- mongo.default.svc.cluster.local ping statistics ---
210 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
command terminated with exit code 1
```

#### test traceroute (bad)

```
$ kc exec -it mongo-67d67fddf9-55zgd -- traceroute -n mongo
traceroute to mongo (10.99.92.189), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.110.7.1  0.228 ms  0.203 ms  0.194 ms
 2  192.168.1.1  0.438 ms  0.519 ms  0.582 ms
 3  10.77.0.1  2.290 ms  3.599 ms  4.396 ms
 4  10.128.132.1  1.851 ms  1.949 ms  2.166 ms
 5  192.168.39.136  2.258 ms  2.421 ms  2.618 ms
 6  10.128.145.5  5.193 ms  6.084 ms  8.301 ms
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

#### traceroute IP (bad)

```
$ kc exec -it mongo-67d67fddf9-55zgd -- traceroute -n 10.99.92.189
traceroute to 10.99.92.189 (10.99.92.189), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.110.7.1  0.190 ms  0.136 ms  0.124 ms
 2  192.168.1.1  0.431 ms  0.485 ms  0.547 ms
 3  10.77.0.1  2.402 ms  3.256 ms  4.040 ms
 4  10.128.132.1  1.780 ms  1.790 ms  1.930 ms
 5  192.168.39.136  2.214 ms  2.209 ms  2.562 ms
 6  10.128.145.5  7.645 ms  8.028 ms  8.284 ms
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

#### iptables from node

```
$ sudo iptables-save | grep mongo
-A KUBE-SEP-HYCP7OGZ3WQCZP76 -s 172.17.0.6/32 -m comment --comment "default/mongo:27017" -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SEP-HYCP7OGZ3WQCZP76 -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/mongo:27017" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.6:27017
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 10.99.92.189/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/mongo:27017 cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 27017 -j KUBE-SVC-VMEO5WN4YXST2YCP
-A KUBE-SVC-VMEO5WN4YXST2YCP -m comment --comment "default/mongo:27017" -j KUBE-SEP-HYCP7OGZ3WQCZP76
```

#### mongo-deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f docker-compose.yml
    kompose.version: 1.6.0 (e4adfef)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: mongo
  name: mongo
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: mongo
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: docker.scnetservices.ru/mongo:dev
        name: mongo
        resources: {}
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /data/db
          name: mongo-claim0
      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
      - name: mongo-claim0
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mongo-claim0
status: {}
```

#### mongo-service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f docker-compose.yml
    kompose.version: 1.6.0 (e4adfef)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: mongo
  name: mongo
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "27017"
    port: 27017
    targetPort: 27017
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: mongo
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

#### mongo-volume0-persistentvolume.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    type: local
  name: mongo-volume0
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity: 
    storage: 5Gi
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/home/docker/mongo"
    type: "DirectoryOrCreate"
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Recycle
  claimRef:
    namespace: default
    name: mongo-claim0
```

#### mongo-claim0-persistentvolumeclaim.yaml

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: mongo-claim0
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
```

But if I connect to container mongo via ssh tunneling it work:

```
$ ssh -fN -l docker -i "~/.minikube/machines/minikube/id_rsa" -L 27017:localhost:27017 $(minikube ip)
sah4ez@PC001:~$ mongo localhost:27017
MongoDB shell version v3.4.9
connecting to: localhost:27017
MongoDB server version: 3.4.2
Server has startup warnings: 
2017-12-21T14:48:20.434+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2017-12-21T14:48:20.434+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2017-12-21T14:48:20.434+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2017-12-21T14:48:20.434+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
> db.hostInfo()
{
    "system" : {
        "currentTime" : ISODate("2017-12-21T16:23:35.940Z"),
        "hostname" : "minikube",
        "cpuAddrSize" : 64,
        "memSizeMB" : 1906,
        "numCores" : 2,
        "cpuArch" : "x86_64",
        "numaEnabled" : false
    },
    "os" : {
        "type" : "Linux",
        "name" : "PRETTY_NAME=\"Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)\"",
        "version" : "Kernel 4.9.13"
    },
    "extra" : {
        "versionString" : "Linux version 4.9.13 (jenkins@jenkins) (gcc version 5.4.0 (Buildroot 2017.02) ) #1 SMP Thu Oct 19 17:14:00 UTC 2017",
        "libcVersion" : "2.19",
        "kernelVersion" : "4.9.13",
        "cpuFrequencyMHz" : "2993.200",
        "cpuFeatures" : "fpu de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 syscall nx lm rep_good nopl eagerfpu pni vmx cx16 x2apic hypervisor lahf_lm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid",
        "pageSize" : NumberLong(4096),
        "numPages" : 487940,
        "maxOpenFiles" : 65536
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

My OS info:

```
sah4ez@PC001:~$ uname -a
Linux PC001 4.8.0-58-generic #63~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 26 18:08:51 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

In example up mongo connected to **minikube** and **Kernel 4.9.13**...

=====

**UPD 2017/12/22**

Now create two pods with mongo into (`mongo` and `mongo2`).
From `mongo2` instance I can connect via dns name `mongo.default.svc.cluster.local:27017` and not connect via service IP. But from `mongo` instance I can't connect via `mongo2.default.svc.cluster.local`.

```
 $ minikube ssh -- sudo iptables-save | grep mongo
-A KUBE-SEP-HYCP7OGZ3WQCZP76 -s 172.17.0.6/32 -m comment --comment "default/mongo:27017" -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SEP-HYCP7OGZ3WQCZP76 -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/mongo:27017" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.6:27017
-A KUBE-SEP-KVDY7RMLLBYXOYB5 -s 172.17.0.8/32 -m comment --comment "default/mongo:27017" -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SEP-KVDY7RMLLBYXOYB5 -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/mongo:27017" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.8:27017
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 10.110.87.97/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/mongo2:27017 cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 27017 -j KUBE-SVC-SDHY4S2JVGEDTQ2U
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 10.98.1.35/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/mongo:27017 cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 27017 -j KUBE-SVC-VMEO5WN4YXST2YCP
-A KUBE-SVC-VMEO5WN4YXST2YCP -m comment --comment "default/mongo:27017" -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.50000000000 -j KUBE-SEP-HYCP7OGZ3WQCZP76
-A KUBE-SVC-VMEO5WN4YXST2YCP -m comment --comment "default/mongo:27017" -j KUBE-SEP-KVDY7RMLLBYXOYB5
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 10.110.87.97/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/mongo2:27017 has no endpoints" -m tcp --dport 27017 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

Attached to `mongo2` pods and connecting to db `mongo` pods.

```
root@mongo2-848b44844f-dbpxx:/# mongo mongo:27017
MongoDB shell version v3.4.2
connecting to: mongo:27017
MongoDB server version: 3.4.2
Server has startup warnings: 
2017-12-22T13:27:46.904+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2017-12-22T13:27:46.904+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2017-12-22T13:27:46.904+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2017-12-22T13:27:46.904+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
> db.hostInfo()
{
    "system" : {
        "currentTime" : ISODate("2017-12-22T14:37:32.222Z"),
        "hostname" : "mongo-6fc9bd6d6c-cc8gh",
        "cpuAddrSize" : 64,
        "memSizeMB" : 1906,
        "numCores" : 2,
        "cpuArch" : "x86_64",
        "numaEnabled" : false
    },
    "os" : {
        "type" : "Linux",
        "name" : "PRETTY_NAME=\"Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)\"",
        "version" : "Kernel 4.9.13"
    },
    "extra" : {
        "versionString" : "Linux version 4.9.13 (jenkins@jenkins) (gcc version 5.4.0 (Buildroot 2017.02) ) #1 SMP Thu Oct 19 17:14:00 UTC 2017",
        "libcVersion" : "2.19",
        "kernelVersion" : "4.9.13",
        "cpuFrequencyMHz" : "2993.200",
        "cpuFeatures" : "fpu de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 syscall nx lm rep_good nopl eagerfpu pni vmx cx16 x2apic hypervisor lahf_lm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid",
        "pageSize" : NumberLong(4096),
        "numPages" : 487940,
        "maxOpenFiles" : 65536
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
> exit
```

Comment: Maybe it doesn't know how to manage ICMP?

Comment: But if I ping via inner ip container 172.27.0.x, all work well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: they technically don't exist.

Long answer: they're iptables rules http://leebriggs.co.uk/blog/2017/02/15/kubernetes-networking-part1.html

Comment: Thank for the link. Yes, kube-proxy not provide ICMP in iptables.

Answer (score 1):

You need a DNS service to map the service name to the dns name (kube-dns).

EDIT:
pinging a service is not possible. Services are routed by iptables and load balanced over the matching pods. What would you be pinging?

Comment: But kube-dns is run:

    po/kube-dns-86f6f55dd5-mrtrm     3/3       Running   3          1h

Comment: You're so right. And the resolv.conf also seems to be ok. I read your overload of info a bit better and nslookup seems to be ok. ICMP seems to be the problem. Hmm, now I think of it. Services work based on iptables and when I check the rules I see UDP and TCP in the rules. So ICMP might not pass the iptables rules. See iptables-save and then grep on the service ip address. Ping to the pod is possible but ping to a service not. That also would be a bit strange because what would you be pinging?

Comment: Yes, you're right. `iptables-save` not contains ICMP. I added **UPD** with interesting behavior.